# Normalized Probabilities in Four Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, simulation, probability

I am trying to replicate my data by generating some random data and putting it through a simulation in R. In this simulation, I created a weight for depth, p1 and weight against density, p2. However, I do not think I have implemented the impact of density correctly.

Below is my simulation

```
nppl <- 100    #number of simulated people we want to run in the for loop
Sites <- LETTERS[1:4]
Depths <- c(.05, .1, .2, .3)
Density <- rep(0,4)
Places <- data.frame(Sites, Depths)
colnames(Places) <- c("Sites", "Depth")
Places <- data.frame(Places, Density=rep(0, 4))
head(Places)
fill <- rep(0, 100)
ppl <- data.frame(ID=1:nppl, Choice=fill, Depth=fill, Density=fill)


p1 <- 1    
p2 <-0.3
#set.seed(42) 
for (i in 1:nppl) {
prob <- p1*Places$Depth * exp(-p2 * Places$Density)  
prob <- prob/sum(prob)   
choice <- sample(as.character(Places$Site), 1, prob=prob)  
ppl[i, ] <- c(i, choice, Places$Depth[Places$Site==choice], Places$Density[Places$Site==choice])   
Places$Density[Places$Site==choice] <-  Places$Density[Places$Site==choice] + 1    
}

ppl
```

Using the formula

```
prob=p1*depth*exp(-p2*density)
```

the normalized probabilities for people 100 should have been .40 for A, .59 for B and almost zero for C and D.

With this strong of a density effect sites C and D should have become very undesirable as densities  increased but that doesn't seem to have happened. What am I doing incorrectly? Is there something wrong with my p1 and p2 values? There shouldn't be a problem using p1=1 but I'm not sure.

Comment: To start, `p2` is assigned a `-0.3` in your code, and then a negative in your `exp()` command which makes density look very desirable...

Comment: @dyrland Opps, it should be 0.3 in the above code. Any idea how to tackle the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that the normalized values, given your constraints, should be .4, .59, ~0, ~0? That's the part I don't understand. As i increase `Density` matters more than `Depth`, and density tends to even out (you're more likely to choose the less dense place which makes that place more dense).

Comment: when I use the equation "p1*Places$Depth * exp(-p2 * Places$Density)" and the values of p1 and p2 and calculate the prob for each site that person 100 would see/encounter, site A and B should have high probabilities (around 0.40 for A, 0.59 for B), and sites C and D should be around 0. The term exp(-p2*density) should be declining as density increases. I don't think my prob is changing with density.